# Backspace and arrow keys not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2022

Most of the time Visual Studio seems to work fine. But occasionally, it gets into a funky editing state. I can still type, but I can't move the cursor with the arrow keys. The arrow keys instead seem to take the focus off the editing window. The backspace doesn't work, but the delete key does. The only solution I have found so far is to close all open documents and reopen them.

Is this a bug, or one of those invisible "features" that just seems a lot like a bug? If not a bug, is there a way to toggle out of this state? Otherwise, is there a fix or patch for this?

Comment: Plenty of feedback reports about this at connect.microsoft.com.  I stopped reading them after a while, nothing definite and lots of users that abandoned their case.  Maybe you'll have more energy.

Comment: How did you find them? The search terms I was using turned up nothing useful.

Comment: I typed "backspace" in the search box.

Comment: I had this too, it turned out to be a plugin that was out of date (ReSharper)

Comment: Cool, let us know the result!

Comment: I had such issue with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Fixed after update ReSharper on Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Still a problem in VS2022 sometimes.  Tried all solutions here. Only restarting VS fixed it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This seems to happen to me when I open a solution and there are files already open. I used to close the files, then close and re-open the solution to fix it, but now I just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Here is the [blog where I found this trick](http://jvides.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/backspace-and-arrow-keys-stop-working/).

Comment: Awesome. This totally did it! Much easier than closing and reopening my windows all the time. Thanks!

Comment: thank you so much!!! I was always reopening file windows every time this happen before I saw this.

Comment: Only MS needs to make a hotkey to bring the focus back to the window you're clicking or typing on... figures. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work today when I had the cursor key problem in VS2022 :(

Comment: Did not work in latest VS in dec 2023. This works: Tools > Options > Search for keyboard > Keybord > 'Reset' button

Answer (score 5):

i'm still seeing this issue even after the ALT + ENTER.

However i did notice if i had more than one window open if i clicked into each file then attempted backspace, eventually it worked on one, and then I seemed back in a working state.

Comment: It's hard to believe I'm still having this issue in 2016 (VS 2015), but here I am. Switching documents, closing the problem doc, then opening it again took care of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I also found this is to be the case when a modal dialog is present, even if it is not visible.  You might check if VS has some alert dialogs in the background.  Closing them returns to normal state.

Comment: I dismissed a bell about a newer version, then closed and re-opened the editor window. That helped.

Answer (score 4):

Try to reset your keyboard's settings. You can do it like this:

1. Go to Tools => Options => Environment.
2. Click on the Keyboard option.
3. Click on the Reset button from right panel.

Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Its only your solution that worked for me today.. Thank you for your time posting this answer..

Comment: This should be the answer to this problem. Thank you for your time and effort in putting together this answer as it was the only one that actually worked! Should have tried it first.

Comment: Problem with this is that you lose any custom keybindings.

Answer (score 3):

Any of the above solutions didn't work for me. However after much trial and error I found out that if you restart VS and load or create another project, followed by opening the trouble project again, it works.